# How to get the Object being pointed by a shared pointer?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, shared, smart-pointers

I have a query. Can we get the object that a shared pointer points to directly? Or should we get the underlying RAW pointer through `get()` call and then access the corresponding object?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You have two options to retrieve a reference to the object pointed to by a `shared_ptr`. Suppose you have a `shared_ptr` variable named `ptr`. You can get the reference either by using `*ptr` or `*ptr.get()`. These two should be equivalent, but the first would be preferred.

The reason for this is that you're really attempting to mimic the dereference operation of a raw pointer. The expression `*ptr` reads "Get me the data pointed to by `ptr`", whereas the expression `*ptr.get()` "Get me the data pointed to by the raw pointer which is wrapped inside `ptr`". Clearly, the first describes your intention much more clearly.

Another reason is that `shared_ptr::get()` is intended to be used in a scenario where you actually *need* access to the raw pointer. In your case, you don't need it, so don't ask for it. Just skip the whole raw pointer thing and continue living in your safer `shared_ptr` world.

Answer (score 27):

[Ken's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491955/how-to-get-the-object-being-pointed-by-a-shared-pointer/6499125#6499125) (or below, depending on how these are sorted) is great.  I don't have enough reputation to comment, otherwise I would.

I'd just like to add that you can also use the `->` operator directly on a `shared_ptr` to access members of the object it points to.

The [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) gives a great overview.

#### EDIT

Now that C++11 is widely adopted, [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) should be preferred to the Boost version. See the dereferencing operators [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*).